# Which options to rsync from vfat to vfat

Tags: android, rsync, vfat

I rsync local mounted vfat partitions.

If I use the `-a` option I get these messages:

```
rsync: chown "/media/new64gb/bar" failed: Operation not permitted (1)
rsync: mkstemp "/media/new64gb/Tryo/Grain de sable/.03. journ\#351es longues.ogg.1NqxoD" failed: Invalid argument (22)
```

How to rsync from vfat to vfat and keep as much file metadata as possible?

Background:

I want to update my internal sdcard of an android device. I opened the device, took the micro sd card, added both (the old and the new) via a card reader via usb.

- /mnt/old32gb
- /mnt/new64gb

Comment: Please refer this link, may be get the solution : `http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/12203/rsync-failed-to-set-permissions-on-error-with-rsync-a-or-p-option`

Answer (score 0):

I found this solution:

```
mount  -t vfat -o iocharset=iso8859-1,shortname=mixed,utf8 /dev/sdb1 /mnt/old32gb
rsync -av --no-g --no-o /mnt/old32gb /mnt/new64gb
```

Now files with umlauts get transferred and the chown error message does not appear any more.